# Why does Entity Framework only call a stored procedure if I return the value and initialize it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 to call a stored procedure that already exists in the SQL server.

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<Log>("Scanning_Scan @Id, @SessionId, @Appname, @Barcode, @Username", _params);
```

This works perfectly so far. The stored procedure has an if statement that selects different  data based on the @Appname parameter it's passed.

If the Stored Procedure returns as

`SELECT * FROM Scanning_Logs WHERE...`

I can get my logs from result using

```
foreach (item in result.ToList())
{
    do something with item.Barcode;
}
```

However I don't actually want to use this data. I can just ignore it. That was the plan, until I found out that one of the stored procedures I was calling from the if statement was returning as a model that is not Log, essentially returning a few random columns and causing an SQL exception since they didn't contain the identity column from Log.

To solve this, when I want to call that specific stored procedure, I return the type as a new class I created.

```
class CartReturn
{
     public string CartNo;
     public string Barcode;
     public string Variation;
     public string Qty;
}
```

And then call

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<CartReturn>("Scanning_Scan @Id, @SessionId, @Appname, @Barcode, @Username", _params);
foreach (item in result.ToList())
{
    var barcode = item.Barcode;
}
```

Really oddly, barcode is returning as blank.. but when I check the stored procedure is still being called. Great! Since I don't need to return anything, (and I only did this to fix the exception when returning a data type I don't care about or use) I'll clean up the code and remove the foreach statement, happy just to call the stored procedure.

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<CartReturn>("Scanning_Scan @Id, @SessionId, @Appname, @Barcode, @Username", _params);
```

This doesn't work.

I really can't explain or understand why this is the issue, but it is. If I take out the foreach loop, the stored procedure is no longer called.

In fact it doesn't seem to be the for loop at all. From testing, it appears that if I don't use the Log being returned to result, then a stored procedure won't be called at all.

WORKS:

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<CartReturn>("Scanning_Scan @Id, @SessionId, @Appname, @Barcode, @Username", _params).ToList();
var i = result[0];
return;
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<CartReturn>("Scanning_Scan @Id, @SessionId, @Appname, @Barcode, @Username", _params);
return;
```

I officially give up... What's going on here?

Comment: That's deferred execution. The `db.Database.SqlQuery` is nothing but a query waiting to be executed.

Comment: Thank you, that appears the correct answer to my question. Now I need to figure out if there's a way to call a stored procedure without deferred execution I suppose.

Comment: That's a contradiction. Anyway, since you don't need the results, why not `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`? (Which executes immediately).

Comment: Sorry, what's a contradiction? Calling a stored procedure without deferred execution? I want to call the stored procedures immediately, what contradictions arise by using Database.ExecuteSqlCommand?

Comment: No that's not a contradiction (I guess I interpreted it as 'run without execution'). So does `ExecuteSqlCommand` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that when you call `.ToList()` you do 2 things:

1. Convert result from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`
2. Actually get the data

While you are in an `IQueryable` your actions can still affect what EF does and what you do will still affect they query, but once you are enumerable you already did extract.

In the top 5 of EF pitfalls, this pit.

There's a good article of the differences here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable-in-linq/

Super important to get our head around and kudos for not accepting weirdness and involving community! In effect the much strange live between what is .net defaults and what is SQL defaults and the creating of queries with or without proper trash data handling explicitly in place, like you described.